# Preloading images and transition for my simple Javascript option for CSS row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This is my first question here, and I'm really in a jam.
I apologize in advance if I am breaking unknown etiquette.

I have an issue where I need to fill the background of a responsive div row with a rotating background image that preloads and also has smooth transitions between images. I'm controlling the COVER setting via the CSS.

I have a crude, but working js sample.. but NO preload and NO smooth transitions. Please advise how I can accomplish preloading with smooth transitions-

The CSS:

```
.row-bkg
    background-size: cover !important;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
```

The Javascript:
( This works but is very basic. I need one with soft transitions that preloads images )

```
$(function() {
    var header = jQuery('.row-bkg');
    var backgrounds = new Array(
        'url(images/banner.jpg)',
        'url(images/banner2.jpg)'
    );
    var current = 0;


    function nextBackground() {
        header.css('background',backgrounds[current = ++current % backgrounds.length]);

        setTimeout(nextBackground, 6000);
    }
    setTimeout(nextBackground, 6000);
    header.css('background', backgrounds[0]);
});
```

Again the above works crudely.. I just need it to gently fade between banners and preload the images so it doesn't show the image download each time.

Any ideas on how to tweak this Javascript to make it do that? Maybe someone can recommend a script that can be used instead that allows me to set details via CSS?

Thanks in advance for your time.

btw.. this is where it can only go in my existing responsive code. I'm adding a custom.css to existing responsive css.

```
<div class="row row-bkg">
```

Comment: This is my original source I need to get working with a smoother transition and ability to preload images. My source  jsfiddle.net/4LFnK

Comment: Have you tried include an extra div inside the header with `position: absolute`, making so you can give a smooth transition.
I've modified your code a little bit check this
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4LFnK/3/)

Comment: Thanks. But I need to make it work off the original CSS .row-bkg only. I'm adding a custom CSS to an existing CSS responsive row. I just tried yours several ways and puts all the other floating menus above it in the rotation sequence as well. Sorry for being so tough. I too thought it would be a simple fix without having to rewrite all the responsive code. At this stage I am unable. Can you merge this http://www.techerator.com/2010/11/how-to-make-a-css-background-slideshow-with-jquery/ into my above javascript?

Comment: I've edited above where it has to land in the existing responsive code. See <div class="row row-bkg">.

Comment: Do you have a fiddle with those changes?

Comment: Sorry Diego, No I don't. It's really the same as the copy source. http://jsfiddle.net/4LFnK/ except my html header code is <div class="row row-bkg">. Part of a bigger responsive code set. My .row-bkg CSS is a little tweaked.

Comment: Diego, Here we go. http://jsfiddle.net/cagdesign/7ghy72kL/

Comment: Ok, it is the same thing check this [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ghy72kL/2/) updated. I have append the div with the transition,

Comment: Thanks. Can you tell me why my entire site now fades to white? The images do change.. but the entire site whites out. I'm sure this is just a tweak?

Comment: I have noticed, I hoped that a 'z-index' solves it, but unfortunately it is not working :(

Comment: Yes, I already attempted z-index. Somehow the transition is going to the top. Overlapping everything instead of just the row

Comment: Yes, I'm close to solve it, it happens because the content inside the .row-bkg have position:static, we need to change it to relative

Comment: I think I have solved it this is the fiddle: [http://jsfiddle.net/7ghy72kL/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/7ghy72kL/3/)

Comment: Wow.. nice man!... I think that is it. Zowie. Let me do some more checking. BRB

Comment: Ugh. It appears to be still transitioning white above the next row and elements not protected in that specific row. Zowie, Let me think...

Comment: Could you give me more details?

Comment: Got it. z-index that overlay row greater. Btw.. The javascript image controls seem backwards. I want to make the image dwell and be instantly show and quickly fade to other. I am unable with the current configuration to accomplish getting the fade out right. If I greater the milliseconds it just increases the transition time. Any way to tweak it?

Comment: Example: 1) Show background image immediately and hold ( per seconds ). 2) Fade out to transition color ( per seconds control ). 3) Be able to set image duration before transition takes place etc. Is that doable? or say like this.... 10 seconds per image. 2 second fade, repeat.

Comment: Yes, try this: [http://jsfiddle.net/7ghy72kL/5/](http://jsfiddle.net/7ghy72kL/5/)

Answer (score 0):

You are very much on the right track...

However, there is not going to be a way to smoothly transition the `background` image -- if you want a smooth fade in/ fade out --- you'll have to go with a different approach in your html:

```
<header>

    <img>
    <img>
    <img>

</header>
```

Which, coincidentally solves your pre-loading issue...

Then, you'll style them so that they are stacked on top of eachother, and do something like this:

$(function() {
        var current = 0;
        var zindex = parseInt("-" + $("header > img").length);

```
    $("header > img").each(function(i) {
        $(this).css("z-index", "-" + i);
    })
    function nextBackground() {
        $("header img:nth-child(" + (current++) + ")").animate({"opacity": "0"},
        400,
        function() {
            $(this).css({
                "z-index" : zindex,
                "opacity" : "1"
            });
        });


        $("header > img").each(function() {
            $(this).css("z-index", parseInt($(this).css("z-index")) + 1);
        });
```

//            current++;
            if( current > $("header > img").length){
                current = 0; 
            }
            setTimeout(nextBackground, 1000);

```
    }

    setTimeout(nextBackground, 1000);
});
```

^Something like that^ ought to work

Here it is in a JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/4LFnK/2/

Now, shall we go over the details of the mechanics of this?

that 400 in there is the animation duration, btw --

All that is happening, you are hiding the image, and then moving it to the very back of the stack... this happens in the animation, and when the animation is done, it resets the opacity back to 1, and sets the zindex to the lowest it needs to go -

Then, it adds 1 to each z-index, so that they all move forward a slot, to make room for the next one that gets moved back - this way, they cycle through, seamlessly.

This code will scale, no matter how many images you stick in there...

Any questions? 
^_^

Comment: Thanks. Sadly, I need a little more info as I tried this with no success. This is what I'm basing my crude working code off above.  http://jsfiddle.net/4LFnK/

Comment: yeah, you're right, that code isn't working. I wrote it in a hurry - give me a minute, and I'll get it to work...

Comment: Many thanks. I really need the original style tweaked because it allows me to set directly to the div row. But I will try anything at this point.

Comment: There you go, works like a charm -! Let me know if you have any questions ^_^

Comment: Thanks again. it's close to working. But my issue is that I have complicated menu css above the row background. This z index is jumping above it and repositioning everything behind it - becoming one in the sequence. Let me think. That original js works great for my purpose. I just needed for it to transition 'better' and all a preload in some manner.

Comment: Ah, did you add in the `header {position:relative;}` ?

Comment: Sadly, Yes, I tried several variations with no success. I need it to work off that .row-bkg. Build it inside the original javascript is the only working option I see.

Comment: Ok, well, if I'm going to help you any further, I'll have to look at all of the code..

Comment: Here is a sample with preload and smoother transitions built into the javascript. http://www.techerator.com/2010/11/how-to-make-a-css-background-slideshow-with-jquery/    I'm just unable to make this work with css .row-bkg

Comment: Nah, just send me your page, or send me the code chopped up into a jsfiddle.

Comment: And you are totally sure that you added `position:relative` to your `.row-bg`/`.mainHeader` ? You may want to make sure that isn't being overridden -

Comment: Thanks. See what I can do. I do know if I could get this var header = jQuery('.row-bkg'); merged into http://www.techerator.com/2010/11/how-to-make-a-css-background-slideshow-with-jquery/ -OR- it's preload / transition into my original javascript. Case solved.

Comment: Solved? --- For the record, my solution to the same problem is less complex - I'm still here, and I'll still help - and I hope I can help you understand what the situation is -

Comment: But if your issue is solved, please don't forget to accept mine as the answer ... and upvote, if you would, please.

Comment: Sorry I mean case solved if I could get the javascript above to mimic the transitions/preload like in http://www.techerator.com/2010/11/how-to-make-a-css-background-slideshow-with-jquery/  I have nothing but big thank you for helping me with options so far. I appreciate all the help.

Comment: Oh yeah, so what's cool about the way I wrote this up, is that you can re-write a certain part to do whatever animation you want... but, if you want it to do that fade to white, I can certainly write that in with ease.