# Preloading images and transition for CSS row with only one image

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I've tried out this solution for rotating background images:

Original Article: [Preloading images and transition for my simple Javascript option for CSS row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26896527/preloading-images-and-transition-for-my-simple-javascript-option-for-css-row)

Now i'm trying to find out how to avoid the flickering if there is only one image.

Comment: The base is an image **slideshow** + the problem occurs if the slideshow only contains **one** image

Answer (score 0):

I believe what you're asking for is a smooth way of loading an image.  Here's an example on how to do that.  If it's not what you're looking for just comment.

```js
$("#background").load(function () {
  $(this).fadeIn(500)
});
```

```css
#background {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:0; /* modify this number acording to how your page is layed out, so -1 will work for some webpages */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="background" src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg3.jpg" />
```

Without the fading effect:

```js
$("#background").load(function () {
  $(this).show();
});
```

```css
body {
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
}
#background {
  display:none;
  position:fixed;
  z-index:0; /* modify this number acording to how your page is layed out, so -1 will work for some webpages */
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img id="background" src="http://neil.computer/stack/bg3.jpg" />
```

Comment: The fading is done nicely via the opacity and works fine with more than one image - there is a fiddle showing the results: http://jsfiddle.net/4LFnK/28/ - i'm just looking for a solution to skip the fading if there is a case with only one image.

Comment: I added an example beneath it without fading... I would recommend fading, however.  The reason why there is a fading is so that when the image has been downloaded there is some transition.  But it is your project and to each their own.  If you could mark as answer that'd be great.

Comment: Yes - fading in is definitely a good idea. My point was just - i do have a slideshow of images on most of the project pages - but in case there is just one image, i don't want it to fade out at all.

Comment: Oh okay.  Wish you the best.

Comment: Thank you! ( I'll try to be more precise on my next subject :)

Answer (score 0):

that's the solution - add this filter in line 9:

if (zindex == -1) return;